# meet error in running "apt-get upgrade" in ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu

I have tried to run  "sudo apt-get upgrade" in my ubuntu system .but I get the log below. It's annoying as I searched google and no results.

**sudo apt-get upgrade**
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-twisted-conch : Depends: python-twisted-core (>= 13.2.0-1ubuntu1.2) but 13.2.0-1ubuntu1 is installed
 python-twisted-mail : Depends: python-twisted-core (>= 13.2.0-1ubuntu1.2) but 13.2.0-1ubuntu1 is installed
 python-twisted-names : Depends: python-twisted-core (>= 13.2.0-1ubuntu1.2) but 13.2.0-1ubuntu1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.

My system version is as follows ,
**cat /proc/version**
Linux version 3.19.0-33-generic (buildd@lgw01-49) (gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) ) #38~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Nov 6 18:17:28 UTC 2015

I tried to follow the instruction of the error info but still get the same error .
**sudo apt-get install -f python-twisted-conch**
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-twisted-mail : Depends: python-twisted-core (>= 13.2.0-1ubuntu1.2) but 13.2.0-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
 python-twisted-names : Depends: python-twisted-core (>= 13.2.0-1ubuntu1.2) but 13.2.0-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies.   Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these. Don't add any package name.

Comment: Your idea of running 'apt-get -f install' is a good start  .  I can then go forward to solve it . Thanks!